# View not redirecting when clicked and onTapGesture is applied to the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code, with the file LycéesRow :

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LycéesRow: View {
    var lycée: Lycée
    
    @State private var customOpacity = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            let firstImage = lycée.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .offset(y: -35)
            
            firstImage
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .offset(y: -35)
                .onTapGesture {
                    customOpacity = 0.0
                }


            let secondImage = lycée.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 355, height: 200)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .offset(x: 5)
                .offset(y: 39.8)
                .onTapGesture {
                    customOpacity = 0.0
                }
                .opacity(customOpacity)

            secondImage

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                Text(lycée.département + ", France")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .opacity(0.5)
                
                Text(lycée.nom)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Text(lycée.ville)
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .opacity(0.9)
            }
            .offset(y: -30)
            .offset(x: 12)
        }
    }
    
    
    struct LycéesRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Group {
                LycéesRow(lycée: lycées[0])
                LycéesRow(lycée: lycées[1])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And LycéesListe :

```
import SwiftUI

struct LycéesListe: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(lycées) { lycée in
                        NavigationLink {
                            LycéeDétail(lycée: lycée)
                        } label: {
                            LycéesRow(lycée: lycée)
                        }
                    }
                }    .navigationTitle("Lycées")
                    .accentColor(Color.clear)
                    .offset(y: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct LycéesListe_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            LycéesListe() }
}
```

My issue is that whenever I tap in LycéesRow on either a rectangle or an image, the onTapGesture does what I ask which is lowering the opacity, but doesn't redirect me to LycéeDétail like it's supposed to do with the NavigationLink. What can I do ?
I attached a screenshot of how the view stays when I click instead of redirecting to LycéeDétail : [image: LycéesListe based on LycéesRow which is supposed to redirect to LycéesDétail when tapped]

Comment: You have included the code for LycéesListe twice.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for telling me, I've just edited it.

Comment: A `NavigationLink` is essentially a button that when tapped, presents a new view. By adding a `.onTapGesture()` over it, you are effectively intercepting the taps. You can layer different gestures with a `.simultaneousGesture()`, but that won't work here because the UI will be confused as to what you want. You need to programmatically navigate here by making everything a button, and then using that to trigger navigation. See [Migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types). Regardless, `NavigationView` is deprecated.